# Invalid property 'parameterValues' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

im using spring batch I'm trying to import data from csv file and after that storing results in xml file using partitioning   concept.

```
 <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"  scope="step"> 

        <property name="resource" value="classpath:ExamResult.txt" />

        <property name="lineMapper">

            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties in POJO -->
                    <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>

                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated by specific characters -->
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                    </bean>
                </property>

            </bean>

        </property>
                 <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->

                 <property name="parameterValues">
                     <map>
                        <entry key="startingIndex" value="#{stepExecutionContext[startingIndex]}" />
                        <entry key="endingIndex" value="#{stepExecutionContext[endingIndex]}" />
                     </map>
                </property>
                <property name="pageSize" value="5" />
                    <property name="rowMapper">
                        <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>

                </bean>
```

because of using this reader im getting following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.flatFileItemReader' defined in class path resource [spring-batch-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'parameterValues' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Bean property 'parameterValues' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'parameterValues' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Bean property 'parameterValues' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

please suggest me to use the suitable reader for partitioning the data file .

i used the FlatFileItemReader

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no method on the `FlatFileItemReader` called `setParameterValues`.  That's what that exception is telling you.  The properties you are configuring there actually look like they are for a JDBC based reader.  A single flat file cannot be partitioned with out of the box components in Spring Batch.  You'll want to split it in order to use partitioning.